# How to insert an handlebarsjs file inside an other

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I want to have something like this:

```
<body>

{{> header}}

</body>
```

Where `header` is referencing to `header.hbs` (`main.hbs` is at the same directory)

I'm creating the partial with:

```
exphbs.create("header", "{{header}}")
```

but `The partial header could not be found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reusable hbs templates are called "partials". You can write these in a separate directory to your page (or "views") templates.

Tell Express where these are stored in your app entry point file - usually `app.js` or `index.js` with

> Handlebars.registerPartials('../path/to/partials/directory')

Then you can use any of your partials templates in your views with below syntax

> {{>partialName}}

See docs for further info:

https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/partials.html#basic-partials

Comment: I'm using express-handlebars, so I done `exphbs.create("header", "{{header}}")` but `The partial header could not be found`, my partial `header.hbs` and `main.hbs` are at the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

try this, in here the header means the file name

```
<body>

{{> header}}

</body>
```

Comment: I'm using express-handlebars, so I done `exphbs.create("header", "{{header}}")` but `The partial header could not be found`, my partial `header.hbs` and `main.hbs` are at the same directory.